# java thread: Thread.interrupt() not working

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, eclipse-rcp

I need to kill a thread that is not created in my code. In other words, the thread object is created by api (Eclipse JFace). Here is my code

```
ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(null);
try {
        IRunnableWithProgress rp = new IRunnableWithProgress(){

            @Override
            public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
                    throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
                Thread.sleep(3000);

                Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
                t.getThreadGroup().list();

                t.interrupt();
            }
        };
        dialog.run(true, true, rp);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thread.currentThread() returns a thread with the name "ModalContext". Line t.getThreadGroup().list() returns the following data:

```
...
Thread[qtp1821431-38,5,main]
Thread[qtp1821431-39,5,main]
Thread[qtp1821431-40,5,main]
Thread[qtp1821431-42 Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18080,5,main]
Thread[DestroyJavaVM,5,main]
Thread[ModalContext,5,main]
```

Variables "dialog" and "rp" do not have reference to their runnable object. And they don't have any method to close or cancel. So I want to kill that thread "ModalContext" directly. Calling t.interrupt() does not work. Thread MoadlContext continues to run. How can I kill the thread? Thanks

Comment: Just for the record, `Thread#interrupt()` is not supposed to kill a thread, but to wake it from `#sleep`. Threads end when they leave their `run` method in one way (`return`) or another (Exception).

Comment: Have a boolean isRunning in the thread and make it true before calling run() method. Have while (isRunning) as first line in the run method. When you want to stop the thread, make the boolean to false.

Comment: @sunrise76 he said the thread code is not under his control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t.interrupt()` does not actually interrupt the thread immediately it only update interrupt status of thread. If your thread contains method which poll the interrupt status (i.e. `sleep` )only then the thread will be interrupted otherwise the thread simply complete the execution and interrupt status will be *ignored*.

Consider following example,

```
class RunMe implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Executing :"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Inside loop for i = " +i);
        }
        System.out.println("Execution completed");
    }

}

public class Interrupted {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunMe runMe = new RunMe();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(runMe);
        t1.start();
        t1.interrupt();//interrupt ignored
        System.out.println("Interrupt method called to interrupt t1");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Interrupt method called to interrupt t1
Executing :Thread-0
Inside loop for i = 1
Inside loop for i = 2
Inside loop for i = 3
Inside loop for i = 4
Inside loop for i = 5
Execution completed
```

Now just add `Thread.sleep(200);` in `run` and you will see the `InterruptedException`.

Answer (score 4):

The [`interrupt` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) doesn't kill the thread.  It sets the "interrupted" status on the `Thread`, and if it's sleeping or waiting on I/O, then that method that it's calling will throw an `InterruptedException`.

However, you call `interrupt` on the current thread after `sleep` finishes, so this will do nothing but set the "interrupted" status.

You can do one of the following:

1. Have another `Thread` call `interrupt` on that `Thread`.  In `run()`, let the method complete if an `InterruptedException` is caught or if [`interrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) returns `true`.
2. Declare a `volatile boolean` variable (say, `isRunning`) that is initialized to `true` in the created thread.  That thread will let the `run()` method complete if it's `false`.  Have another `Thread` set it to `false` at the appropriate time.