# Stop Thread which doesn't include while statement

Tags: java

All answers are about how to stop **loop** of some thread, but what if I don't have a loop but I still want to stop a thread before it executes/processes all lines?

For example I have a thread which usually runs for 7-10 seconds and then dies (terminates):

```
mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

    // some code here 
    // some here  
    // some here
    // some here          
    // some here
    // all lines takes about 7-10 seconds

   }
});
```

If I started a thread and after 2 or 3 seconds I need to stop it, then how to do it and don't wait 10 seconds?

Comment: If your thread is in a blocking call, call interrupt. This is the preffered way in java to cancel IO and blocking calls.

Comment: Do you know from inside the `run` method that you need to stop processing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you kill a thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java)

Comment: @FazoM there they talk about `while`

Comment: Create a flag and check it  before doing something. You can't guarantee immediate interruption in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: @user25 I don't see any mention of `while` in the linked question. Anyway, good look with solving your problem

Comment: @FazoM most answers there about how to stop `while` (though author didn't mention it, he just asked a short general question, I asked a more specific question because I know it's not easy to stop/kill and .stop method is deprecated), and no answers like I got in my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450107/4548520

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your thread is not blocked, and is actually processing stuff, then interrupting it might not help.  You can code the thread to check for the interrupt flag on the current thread and then stop if it sees that the flag has been set.

This is how you check to see if the current thread has been interrupted.

```
Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();
```

So you would have to code your thread like this...

```
mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

    // some code here 
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;
    // some here  
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;
    // some here
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;
    // some here          
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;
    // some here
    // all lines takes about 7-10 seconds    
   }
});
```

Then you can go ahead and interrupt the mThread and it will have an effect.  Though it will still continue processing the current `some here` step it is on.

Comment: this is what I don't like to put conditions before every line :) and also it still be waiting some lines to finish, what about to interrupt while one line is still executed?

Comment: but I guess it's the only way

Comment: If the line is blocked, then the interrupt will stop the execution of that line.  It really comes down to weather or not the code being interrupted is interruptible.  No way around that.  A lot of good JDK code will check to see if it is interrupted before continuing processing.

Comment: Just note that in general, `interrupt` is not meant for **stopping** a thread. It's mainly used for interrupting a `sleep` or other **idle periods**, not necessarily to stop the thread.

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation

The preferred way is to implement a stopping mechanism in the thread. You can also try to observe the `interrupt` flag. You can interrupt from outside using the `Thread#interrupt` method and the thread can check the flag using `Thread#isInterrupted` and `Thread#interrupted` (see documentation of [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)).

There is **no way** to force a thread from outside to stop without the thread actually implementing the logic by itself. There is the `Thread#stop` method but it is **deprecated** and should never be used. From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--):

> **Deprecated**. This method is **inherently unsafe**. Stopping a thread with `Thread.stop` causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked `ThreadDeath` exception propagating up the stack). If any of the objects previously protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become visible to other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior. Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it is to stop running. If the target thread waits for long periods (on a condition variable, for example), the interrupt method should be used to interrupt the wait. For more information, see [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

---

### Solution

You could modify the thread like this:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean mShouldStop = false;

    public void shutdown() {
        mShouldStop = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // First line ...
        if (mShouldStop) return;
        // Second line ...
        if (mShouldStop) return;
        // Third line ...
        if (mShouldStop) return;
    }
}
```

So you need to periodically check the flag and then manually abort.

Usually such threads have some kind of `while (true)` loop. In this case it gets easier, you could do:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!mShouldStop) {
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

Depending on your application you might interpret the **interruption flag** as signal for a thread shutdown. Then your code could look like

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        // Do something ...
    }
}
```

---

### Note

The `mShouldStop` needs to be `volatile` to ensure it is updated correctly for the `Thread`. See the tutorial by Oracle for [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Comment: I think you need to mark that `boolean` as `volatile`

Comment: or without using `boolean` but `isInterrupted` like here I guess would be a little better `https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450107/4548520

Comment: Yup. It depends. Sometimes you want the *interruption flag* to have a different meaning. Like only a notification from outside "*hey, something has changed, please check*". So it can be part of a regular logic instead. Especially if the thread `sleep`s regularly, then this can be used to interrupt the sleep.

Comment: If one of the steps is blocked, just setting the `mShouldStop` won't stop it.  You still have to interrupt the thread.  Interrupting will ensure that any blocking steps get stopped.  The flag is nice but the `isInterrupted` is just as good and will capture situations where your thread was attempted to be stopped from code that was not specifically coded to set your `mShouldStop` flag.  Hence, IMHO, using `isInterrupted` as your flag is a more full proof way to stop the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You interrupt the thread with [`mThread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29). But, for this to work, your thread needs to check the interrupt status (by sleeping). Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32486830/820410).

For more details, refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671049/how-do-you-kill-a-thread-in-java).

Comment: @downvoters: care to share your opinion? Or do you prefer to be a dark judge?

Comment: Interrupt does not stop a thread if the thread does not manually listen to the interrupt and then implement a stop-logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the interrupt status in your thread.  Something like this

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ThreadInterruptor {


    private static class Worker implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                IntStream.range(0, Short.MAX_VALUE).forEach(i ->noop());
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("i got interrupted");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        private void noop(){}
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Worker());
        thread.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        thread.interrupt();
    }

}
```